# travis not find my package golang

Tags: go, travis-ci

my structure project

```
currency-quote-api - 
                |
                |- scraping/ file.go
                |- api/ file.go
                |- tests/ test.go
                |- main.go
```

When I run the tests in travis CI i get the following error

```
tests/scraping_test.go:4:2: cannot find package "currency-quote-api/scraping" in any of:
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.10.2.linux.amd64/src/currency-quote-api/scraping (from $GOROOT)
/home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/matheussilva97/currency-quote-api/Godeps/_workspace/src/currency-quote-api/scraping (from $GOPATH)
/home/travis/gopath/src/currency-quote-api/scraping
```

what I doing wrong?

my .travis.yml

```
sudo: false

language: go

go:
  -  1.10.2

notifications:
    email: false

before_script:
  - go get github.com/gorilla/mux
  - go get github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

script: 
  - go test -v ./tests/
```

Comment: It seems your project source code is not available under GOPATH.

Comment: Is this a Travis-only problem? How do you compile it on your machine? Also: Your package layout looks suspicious. Are you sure what yuo are doing here?

Comment: I can't configure my packages like that? Do I need to put all the files at the root of the project? I just run main.go and works, I import other packes in import, like this  import("currency-quote-api/api")

Comment: Read How to Write Go Code and stick to it word for word.

Comment: Go (specifically the go cli tool) is very opinionated. It looks like you've attempted to deviate from the standard without really understanding how or what you've done. https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not implicitly get all packages:

`before_script:
  - go get -t -v ./...`

For test, since each test can have its own dependency (depending on which package you put your test in), you should have a script like this:

```
for d in $(go list ./... | grep -v vendor); do
  go test -race -coverprofile=profile.out -covermode=atomic $d
done
```